# Javascript - How to ensure a callback is invoked with specific arguments?

Tags: javascript, callback, parameter-passing

I would like to pass a callback function (that contains parameters) to an object and ensure that it is invoked using specific argument values. I'd like to do this in such a way that these values do not need to be passed in as well. Is this possible?

Here is an (unusable) example of what I'm trying to do:

```
this.object = new Object(callback(val)); //val is the value I'd like the object to use
```

The callback could be one of a variety of functions with unique parameters. As such, I'd like to refrain from having to pass in the values separately.

An example:

```
//Instances of the same object with different callbacks
this.object1 = new Object(callback(val1, val2));
this.object2 = new Object(callback(val));
this.object3 = new Object(callback(val1, val2, val3));
```

As you can see, it is not feasible to pass in the additional arguments.

I could pass the callback in like this:

```
this.object = new Object( function() { this.callback.call(val) } );
```

...but since the callback is outside the scope of Object, it requires me to either pass a reference to the caller to access it, or access the caller in some other manner.

What is my best course of action?

---

**Update:**

I am creating a `MenuSystem` with `Buttons`. Each `Button` functions differently according to given callback methods - the primary function being for click events. An object exists in `MenuSystem` that encapsulates all the different functionality (methods) a button can possibly use. These methods are what's passed in as callbacks to the buttons. The `Button` may need to "own" the method if it modifies its own attributes. This will require a `function.call()`

TL;DR:

`MenuSystem` has [ `UIMethods` + `UIElement` ]

`UIElement` uses [ `UIMethods.someMethod()` ] for functionality purposes

`someMethod()` may modify attributes of `UIElement` which requires `function.call()`

---

Comment: Wrap it in a function like you're doing and bind the scope to the wrapper function

Comment: `callback.bind(object, arg1, arg2, arg3, ... )`

Answer (score 1):

```
this.object = new Object(function() { this.callback(val) }.bind(this));
```

That will bind the scope so `this` refers correctly.

Comment: No need for an intermediate function: `new Object(this.callback.bind(this, val));`.

Comment: @JamesMonger @FelixKling:
Will this successfully work if I need to use a function.call(), such that:
`this.object = new Object(function() { this.callback.call(this, val) }.bind(this));`

I'm assuming this will cause issues

Comment: @sookie: Why do you want to use `call` here? `this.callback()` and `this.callback.call(this)` are equivalent.

Comment: @FelixKling: I need to invoke the callback as the `Object` but also get access to it since it is a function of `caller`

Comment: @sookie: I think you need to provide a better and complete(!) example. Since we don't even know what `Object` does (I assume it's not the default `Object` constructor function), we don't even know how the callback is going to be executed. Please read [mcve].

Comment: @FelixKling: Your right. I didn't think the solution would clash with the fact that I need to use `function.call()` so I didn't add it in. Editing now.

Comment: @FelixKling: Question updated